# dispatcherServletRegistration Spring boot exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

Help please, I try to put Vaadin on my (Spring boot) server and after I set up a simple example, I get the following error:

The bean 'dispatcherServletRegistration', defined in class path resource [com/vaadin/flow/spring/SpringBootAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Then, to correct the error, I write in application.prop:
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

and get the following error:

Parameter 1 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' that could not be found.

POM.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

    com.lopamoko
    cloudliquid
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    jar

```
<name>cloudliquid</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-annotation-plugin-repo</id>
        <url>http://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>

    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from com.lopamoko.cloudliquid.repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.leon0399</groupId>
        <artifactId>dadata</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-gson</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
        <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Its my Main application:

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@EntityScan("com/lopamoko/cloudliquid/dataModel")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages =    "com.lopamoko.cloudliquid.repository")
public class CloudliquidApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CloudliquidApplication.class, args);
    System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        System.out.println(beanName);
    }
    FirebaseConfig firebaseConfig = new FirebaseConfig();
    firebaseConfig.configurateFirebaseApplication();

}


@Bean
public DadataService dadataService() {
    return new DadataServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public DadataClient dadataClient() {
    return Feign.builder()
            .client(new OkHttpClient())
            .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
            .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
            .logger(new Slf4jLogger(DadataClient.class))
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
            .target(DadataClient.class, "https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/address");
}

@Bean
public CustomerDeliveryService customerDeliveryService() {
    return new CustomerDeliveryServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public OrderService orderService() {
    return new OrderServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public YandexService yandexService() {
    return new YandexServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public CategoryService categoryService() {
    return new CategoryServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public ShopService shopService() {
    return new ShopServiceImpl();
}


@Bean
public CommentService commentService() {
    return new CommentServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public RatingService ratingService() {
    return new RatingServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public ProductService productService() {
    return new ProductServiceImpl();
}


@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
        }
    };
})
```

And Vaadin sample:

```
@Route("/TestMySelf")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
  public MainView() {
    Label label = new Label("Hello its CloudLiquid");
  }
}
```

Comment: For starters stop mixing Spring Boot versions (2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.1) that is trouble bound to happen. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework. In short remove the `<version>` from alle `org.springframework.boot` dependencies, those are all managed by the starter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the version of `vaadin-spring-boot-starter` you are using ?

From [this](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/331#issuecomment-435068326) , it said this is the known issues when certain old version of `vaadin-spring-boot-starter` is used with Spring Boot 2.1 and it will be fixed in some newer release :

> We have another working workaround and are also close to finding the
>   proper fix without the need for the workaround. Regardless which
>   approach we use first, next week we should have platform releases that
>   work with Spring Boot 2.1. (v10, v11 and v12)
>
> Sorry for keeping you on hold before being able updating to Spring
>   Boot 2.1, we should have looked at this earlier - my bad.

Then from the release note [here](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/releases/tag/10.1.0), it said version 10.1.0 supports Spring Boot 2.1. So my advice is to upgrade the `vaadin-spring-boot-starter` to at least 10.1.0 or the latest version.